# generate a random phrase out of 71 possibilities

Tags: javascript, if-statement, bots, discord

I'm extremely new to working with javascript. I'm working on a bot for my discord server that will randomly generate a phrase out of an array. I have tried several different formats of codes from what I've seen posted here and around the web but the commands wont work when i run it, and sometimes will stop the bot from running all together. Here is an example of code I have implemented right now:

```
bot.on('message', msg=>{
    if (msg.content === "!command"){
        if (num==1){
             msg.reply("phrase");
             } else if (num==2){
             msg.reply("phrase");
             } else if (num==3){
             msg.reply("phrase");
             } else if (num==4){
             msg.reply("phrase");
             } else if (num==5){
             msg.reply("phrase");
             } else {
             msg.reply("I should never say this");
             }
```

I thank everyone in advance for any help you can give, as I am struggling a lot with this!

Comment: How exactly does it "not work"?  Where does `num` come from? What have you tried to debug the problems?

Answer (score 1):

You can define an array of phrases and use `Math.random` to choose it:

```js
const phrases = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length);

const phrase = phrases[index];

console.log(phrase);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Javascript array and it will be much more efficient. It would be something like this:

```
phrases = ["Hey","Hi","what's up?", "beat it!"];
bot.on('message', msg=>{
  if (msg.content === "!command"){
    //not sure where 'num' was supposed to come from but this'll give you a
    //random number the size of the array
    num == Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length);
    msg.reply(phrases[num]);
  }
}
```